how to trigger a Jenkin job when a GitLab merge request is updated?
Currently in GitLab when someone merge in a merge request, my Jenkin job is triggered.
However, if someone update a merge request, then my Jenkin job is not triggered. So for example, if someone misspelled a word in merge request Description, it wont get reprocess by my Jenkin job. How do I fix this?
In GitLab, I have my webhook set up and Merge request events selected. So if a "merge request is created, updated, or merged", it should call the webhook URL and I confirmed it is with the Recent events logs.
In Jenkin, I have Accepted Merge Request Events selected. This means it will only trigger on merged merge request event right? What do I trigger on update here?


The rebuild open merge requests is set to Never should be a value. I forgot what it is.
